# NavigationLink deinit ObservedObject after background task is done

Tags: swiftui, combine, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a problem with deallocating `SecondVM` each time when I push to new View from my `ContentView` and `ContentVM` finishes his work.

**Description**

After pushing to `Second` View, the `ObservableObject` is deallocated after task in `ContentVM` is done.

My example code bellow `ContentView` and `ContentVM:

```
final class ContentVM: ObservableObject {

@Published var title = "Start"

init() {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
        self.title = "Changed"
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {

  @ObservedObject var vm = ContentVM()

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: Second()) {
                Text("Go To second")
            }
            Spacer()
                .frame(height: 40)
            Text(vm.title)
        }
      }   
   }
}
```

and `Second` and `SecondVM`

```
final class SecondVM: ObservableObject {

  @Published var name: String = ""

  func getName() {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
        self.name = "TEST"
    }
  }
}

struct Second: View {

  @ObservedObject var vm = SecondVM()

  var body: some View {
    Text(vm.name)
    .padding(50)
        .background(vm.name.isEmpty ? Color.white : Color.black)
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        .onAppear {
            self.vm.getName()
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see on the video bellow problem appears only, when I push to `Second` View. The Black rectangle appears correctly and after task from `ContentVM` is done then, this black rectangle disappears because of deallocating `SecondVM`. How to avoid this kind of behaviour?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution - make link destination equatable, so when ContentView updated on own state change it does not recreate destination view (which otherwise is what happens and is origin of observed issue).

Tested with Xcode 11.5b2

```
// in ContentView, id can be any type but constant in this case
NavigationLink(destination: Second(id: 1).equatable()) {
    Text("Go To second")
}

// SecondView
struct Second: View, Equatable {
    let id: Int
    static func == (lhs: Second, rhs: Second) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }

  @ObservedObject var vm = SecondVM()

  // .. other code
```